# Utility of using function inside a function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python programming. I have come across this line of codes to sort a dict by value (Python 2.4 or greater):

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)): print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

Please help me to understand the utility of using a function(here lambda function) inside another function using argument 'key'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want different results when using `sorted`: most common uses are ascending and descending order. in your example you are sorting a dictionary, for which ascending and descending doesn't mean anything. the lambda gives `sorted` the power to sort anything, the way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted)'s `key` attribute work as described bellow:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None (compare the elements directly).

`sorted` call `key`'s function on each item within the `dict` to compute sorted output.

The utility is to let user to define complex sorting mechanisms.